# PHP NuSOAP server is working but client displays nothing

Tags: php, web-services

i am new in web services. i have created a web service by following [this tutorial](http://www.ahowto.net/php/creating-webservice-server-and-client-using-nusoap/). Server is working fine but when i run client in browser its displaying nothing.

*server.php* is same as in the tutorial.

*client.php*

```
<?php
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

//This is your webservice server WSDL URL address
$wsdl = "http://localhost/web%20service/client.php?wsdl";

//create client object
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, 'wsdl');

$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
// Display the error
echo '
Constructor error

' . $err;
// At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
    exit();
}

//calling our first simple entry point
$result1=$client->call('hello', array('username'=>'achmad'));
print_r($result1); 

//call second function which return complex type
$result2 = $client->call('login', array('username'=>'john', 
'password'=>'doe') );
//$result2 would be an array/struct
print_r($result2);
?>
```

i am using wamp server.

Comment: Can you show your wsdl file content?

Comment: @Jeffrey Hitosis, Can you please tell me what is wsdl file and how to create and use it? it is also not mentioned in the tutorial i am following.

Comment: If you run http://localhost/web%20service/client.php?wsdl to your browser it will display the xml file generated.

Comment: i run it and it is displaying only blank page. please help

Comment: Then I think, that's where the problem is, it's in your SOAP server not in the client. It should display XML when you access your soap server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. I just removed a blank space from project folder name and now its working fine.